# Regular Expression formatting Java

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling to come up with a regular expression to format my input file. 
Sample of input file:

```
john m smith 12121993 paul bright 1111882.
```

The output I would like is

```
John M Smith 12/12/1993 Paul Bright 11/11/1882.
```

**Code:**

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class FormatNames{
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

    String inputFileName = "input";
    String outputFileName = "output.txt";
    String regex = "?";


    File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);

    // Read input and write output
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputFileName);
    while(m.find()){
        if(m.group().length() !=0){
            out.print(m.group());
        }
    }


    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

}

Comment: What regex did you try?

Comment: Don't use import *, use the packages you actually need.

Comment: Try to define in words what kind of pattern the data in the file forms. That will make it easily to translate into regex. E.g. "A bunch of letters" can be easily translated to `[a-zA-Z]+`. Other than that, you are not reading anything from your input file. And you'll need to remember to print the slashes for the date.

Comment: (+^(\w\s) ?(\w\s)(\d{8})) I tried this as my understanding was this regex means,  1 or more , start of line since there may be hundreds of lines with group 1 looking for any word and a space, group 2 looking for the middle name and a space but if its not there carry on and group 3 any 8 digits.

Comment: 1. Why use a regex?  2. You haven't actually specified the input nearly clearly enough for someone to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem consists of two parts:

1) Finding the numerical strings containing the date information within your text string.

2) Converting it to a date.

Here's my solution

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


class FormatNames
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = "john m smith 12121993 paul bright 1111882. ";
        StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer(s, " .");   


        SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {
            String string1= st.nextToken();
            Integer date = null;
            try
            {
                date = Integer.parseInt(string1);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            if (date != null)
            {
                String formattedDate = newFormat.format(date);
                System.out.print(formattedDate);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(string1);
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

You have a little problem with the "." at the end of the string missing, but I am sure you can figure that one out yourself. It depends very much on what the import format is like and if there is any variation to it.